# can't edit class file with recaf.0.9 without re-compile

Tags: decompilation, java, byte-code

I have this java code

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I compile to class file, run it , and all fine.

I want to edit it via class file.

I open the `HelloWorld.class` with recaf.0.9, click on recompile, than I edit the code and save it, but the code not changes.

How can I edit .class file and not recompile it , and not working with bytecode.

I want for example add if else to this code(via the class file)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I edit .class file and not recompile it , and not working with bytecode.

These requirements are contradictory. You have to choose one or the other.

There are two main ways to edit Java code. You can either decompile the classfile, edit the decompiled source, and then try to compile it again, or you can edit it directly at the bytecode level using a bytecode disassembler and assembler such as [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) or a bytecode editor such as Recaf.

Decompilation and recompilation is unreliable, since the process is lossy in both directions, so it will generally only work in simple cases. You're better off editing the bytecode directly, since this is faster and guaranteed to work for all classfiles, but it does require you to understand bytecode. Note that Recaf is also lossy (unlike Krakatau), although it won't matter unless you're doing something highly unusual.

Comment: 1)why Decompilation and recompilation is lossy2) if I want to edit directly the bytecode, how can I check if I done it well ? wach it on JD-GUI?  3) by the way, if I edit 1 function from big class via bytecode, but edit only the internal logic of this functon, is that influence on another functon?   thank you!

Comment: If you only edit the bytecode of one method, that won't affect any other methods. As for how to check your results, you could just disassemble it again.

Comment: I tried to edit bytecode (.class file) with http://cs.ioc.ee/~ando/jbe/   .I have class file with some functions ,  I tried to edit 1 func that get some arguments and have some local var .When I put this class file on intellij I see the name of arguments and name of local var .   but when I click on save on JBE , the name of all arguments and local var changed to var1,var2  . why? I want to edit byte code without delete anything

Comment: Most likely, the tool you used didn't preserve the metadata attributes. Have you tried using Krakatau? That will preserve everything by default.

Comment: I don't understand how to use Krakatau , Is there any gui to use it on windows? I only want to edit bytecode, I dont want to re-compaile code and can you tell me pleaase how can I only edit  byte code of 1 function from .class file that include few funcrion (I don't want touch another functions) without re-compaile it and saving on metadata?  ot o you know another tool with gui for that ? thanks!

Comment: @cdcsccd You disassemble the classfile into a textual `.j` file, edit that, and then reassemble it into a classfile. There's no compilation going on, only disassembly and reassembly, which are lossless in the case of Krakatau.

Comment: that you, Do you know another tool to edit bytecode but without lossless? I think that after I reassembly the j file there is some changes of lable numbers on another code

Comment: @cdcsccd If you pass `-roundtrip` to Krakatau, then nothing at all will change. If you don't, then only things which don't matter to execution, like the ordering of the constant pool will change.

Comment: 1) roundtrip  only help when Krakatau convert .class file to j file , but when I return j file to .class file  there is no roundtrip   so the ordering of const changed,                       2) by the way do you recommend only on Krakatau to edit bytecode without loosless, or do you know another tool to do that?, thank!

Comment: @cdcsccd If you use Krakatau to disassemble a classfile to a .j file and then reassemble the same .j file into a .class file, you'll get back the exact same classfile you started with. And yes I would recommend Krakatau. As far as I know, it is the only tool that is 100% lossless, but other tools should be good enough for most circumstances.